# Word Boundaries in R for Word Filtering

Tags: r, pattern-matching, filtering, stringr, word-boundary

I am filtering some pathway names, and I want to include only pathways that contains: `"HEMATOPOIETIC", "ERYTHROCYTE", "ERYTHROID", "STEM", "STEMNESS", "HEMATOPOIESIS"` and make a bar plot of the results. This is my script so far:

```
obese <- gsea_obese %>% 
  filter(FDR.q.val < 0.25) %>% 
  filter(NOM.p.val < 0.05) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(NAME, "HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS")) %>% 
  arrange(FDR.q.val)

ggplot(obese, aes(reorder(NAME, NES), NES)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=FDR.q.val)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Pathway", y="Normalized Enrichment Score",
       title="Enriched Genes JAK2 vs WT in Obese mice")
```

on my results, i got unwanted pathways like `"REACTOME_NEURONAL_SYSTEM", "REACTOME_CYTOKINE_SIGNALING_IN_IMMUNE_SYSTEM", "GOBP_IMMUNE_SYSTEM_DEVELOPMENT", ...` and I noticed that it is due to the word `"SYSTEM"` containing `"STEM"`. I tried using `"\\b"` but instead it does not return (or does not match) with any pathway names at all. Maybe I have mispositioned `"\\b"` in the script, so any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
Here's a sample of the input:

```
gsea_obese <- c(
  "RAMALHO_STEMNESS_UP",
  "IVANOVA_HEMATOPOIESIS_INTERMEDIATE_PROGENITOR",
  "BYSTRYKH_HEMATOPOIESIS_STEM_CELL_QTL_CIS",
  "IVANOVA_HEMATOPOIESIS_EARLY_PROGENITOR",
  "RIZ_ERYTHROID_DIFFERENTIATION",
  "BYSTRYKH_HEMATOPOIESIS_STEM_CELL_AND_BRAIN_QTL_CIS",
  "RIZ_ERYTHROID_DIFFERENTIATION_CCNE1",
  "REACTOME_CYTOKINE_SIGNALING_IN_IMMUNE_SYSTEM",
  "GOBP_ERYTHROCYTE_HOMEOSTASIS",
  "REACTOME_NEURONAL_SYSTEM",
)
```

the output I expected is that they do not include the ones outside of the pattern I have specified. i manage to solve it with
`filter(str_detect(NAME, "HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|\\b STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS"))`, however i also try it with  `filter(str_detect(NAME, "\\b HEMATOPOIETIC|\\b ERYTHROCYTE|\\b ERYTHROID|\\b STEM|\\b STEMNESS|\\b HEMATOPOIESIS"))` and i don't understand why this script does not return any match.

Comment: Where did you put the `\b`? Can you please share `dput(gsea_obese)` so we can copy/paste some sample data for testing? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Are you trying to get partial matches? Otherwise something like `keep<-c("HEMATOPOIETIC", "ERYTHROCYTE", "ERYTHROID", "STEM", "STEMNESS", "HEMATOPOIESIS")` along with `... filter(NAME %in% keep) ...` would be better because that would do exact matches. Otherwise `stringr::str_detect(NAME, "\\b(HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS)\\b")` might be what you are after

Comment: @MrFlick hi, thanks for comment! i made some edits to the question regarding your first point. i tried both and it somehow does not return any match still

Comment: Please be mindful of sample data, including _trying it yourself_. In this case, your `gsea_obese` is a parsing error, `argument 11 is empty`, due to the trailing comma. It's easy to fix, but it can be frustrating troubleshooting code that you've never run yourself. (Also, why do we need to care about `ggplot` here? I suggest reducing unnecessary code out a question makes it more readable, reduces unnecessary confusion, etc.)

Comment: Also, "outside of the pattern I have specified" assumes that our interpretation of what you want is correct ... it's often better in the long run to be explicit about what you are expecting, as in *"the output I expect is true for all except 8 and 10"* (assuming that's what you mean).

Comment: @r2evans apologies, i included the `ggplot` because i was trying to plot the results and i noticed it did not match any because my plot returned nothing. thought it might be necessary

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the context @daddabi

Answer (score 3):

`_` does not constitute a word boundary:

```r
grepl("\\ba\\b", "_a_")
# [1] FALSE
```

This is because `\b` in regex *"matches the empty string at either edge of a word"*, and a "word" is typically `[[:alnum:]_]` (it explicitly includes the underscore). (See [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) for all of that with more explanations.)

We need to refine the regex to look for specific boundary conditions. Using `(^|_)` will look for a `_`-boundary or beginning-of-string, similarly for EOS:

```r
grepl("(^|_)a(_|$)", c("a_", "_a_", "_a", "_aa_"))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

We will also need to group the pattern strings into a `(`-group. I think that means your regex should look something like this:

```r
"(^|_)?(HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS)(_|$)"
```

If there are other boundary-like characters, you may want to include them in those book-end patterns. For instance, if a boundary could be a space or underscore, then you might use

```r
"(^|[_ ])?(HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS)([_ ]|$)"
```

ala

```r
txt <- c("REACTOME_NEURONAL_SYSTEM", "SOMETHING_STEM_ELSE", "STEM_QUUX")
grepl("(^|[_ ])?(HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS)([_ ]|$)", txt)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Using your added data:

```r
gsea_obese <- c(
  "RAMALHO_STEMNESS_UP",
  "IVANOVA_HEMATOPOIESIS_INTERMEDIATE_PROGENITOR",
  "BYSTRYKH_HEMATOPOIESIS_STEM_CELL_QTL_CIS",
  "IVANOVA_HEMATOPOIESIS_EARLY_PROGENITOR",
  "RIZ_ERYTHROID_DIFFERENTIATION",
  "BYSTRYKH_HEMATOPOIESIS_STEM_CELL_AND_BRAIN_QTL_CIS",
  "RIZ_ERYTHROID_DIFFERENTIATION_CCNE1",
  "REACTOME_CYTOKINE_SIGNALING_IN_IMMUNE_SYSTEM",
  "GOBP_ERYTHROCYTE_HOMEOSTASIS",
  "REACTOME_NEURONAL_SYSTEM"
)
keep <- c("HEMATOPOIETIC", "ERYTHROCYTE", "ERYTHROID", "STEM", "STEMNESS", "HEMATOPOIESIS")
ptn <- paste0("(^|[ _])(", paste(keep, collapse = "|"), ")([ _]|$)")
ptn
# [1] "(^|[ _])(HEMATOPOIETIC|ERYTHROCYTE|ERYTHROID|STEM|STEMNESS|HEMATOPOIESIS)([ _]|$)"

stringr::str_detect(gsea_obese, ptn)
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!! i'm not very familiar with regex, so this is very helpful and it worked like wonders. appreciate it very much ^^